# Decode GPS data and tracker from SMS message

Tags: gps

I have a GPS tracker that sends the following sms message when sent a *1234*x# sms.

UnArmed;Engine:off;Door:off;LAC:2728;CID:EE62;Signal Strength:17$GPRMC,150105.00,A,0637.99406,N,00320.91465,E,0.022,,181011,,,A*76

I am trying to do 2 things.

1. Decode the message so I can create a server for it.
2. Possibly identify the tracker model to see if it also has GPRS capabilities.

I "inherited" it from an existing health mission that tracks rural ambulances, and the documentation is non existent and also the supplier has closed shop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you ever solve this generally?  I have a SMSes coming from tracking collars on lions to decode, and no docs either...  Mine doesn't have such obvious payload and online decoders really make much sense of the PDU

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything after the $ is a standard [NMEA sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183). Everything before the $ looks pretty straightforward.